# Windows Service hosting Web API 2 via Owin Starts and Immediately Stops with no Exceptions Thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin

The title sums up my issue. I have `try-catch` blocks around the service's `OnStart` method and the `Main` method in the service, and no exception is ever thrown. The service starts and immediately stops, with the following message:

> The Foo service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some
>   services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services
>   or programs.

The same behavior can be observed on the test server, so it is not machine-dependent. I've verified that the configuration file is present and contains the appropriate settings.

I cannot see any obvious reason why this would be occurring. Can someone please take a look at this and shed some light on it? I've consulted other, similar questions and none of them shed any light on this particular service.

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

**WebApiService.cs:**

```
public partial class WebApiService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly IConfig config;
    private IDisposable webApp;

    public WebApiService()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.config = UnityBootstrapper.Initialize().Resolve<IConfig>();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new ApplicationEventLog(new Config()).WriteError(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var baseUrl = $"http://*:{this.config.WebApiHttpPort}";

            this.webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new ApplicationEventLog(this.config).WriteError(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.webApp?.Dispose();
        this.webApp = null;
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        this.webApp?.Dispose();
        this.webApp = null;
    }
}
```

**WebApiService.Designer.cs**

```
partial class WebApiService
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.ServiceName = "Foo";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public static class Program
{
    public static bool IsConsoleApp = false;
    public static bool LogRequests = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && args.Any(a => a.ToLower().In("l", "-l", "/l")))
            {
                LogRequests = true;
            }

            if (args.Length > 0
                && args[0].ToLower().In("c", "-c", "/c"))
            {
                RunAsApp();
            }
            else
            {
                RunAsService();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new ApplicationEventLog(new Config()).WriteError(e);
        }
    }

    private static void RunAsService()
    {
        Program.IsConsoleApp = false;

        var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                                      {
                                          new WebApiService()
                                      };
        ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }

    private static void RunAsApp()
    {
        Program.IsConsoleApp = true;

        var config = UnityBootstrapper.Initialize().Resolve<IConfig>();
        var url = $"http://*:{config.WebApiHttpPort}";

        Console.WriteLine($@"Running. Hosted at: {url}");
        Console.WriteLine(@"Press ENTER to exit.");

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }

        Program.IsConsoleApp = false;
    }
}
```

**LogController.cs:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/log")]
public class LogController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IContextFactory contextFactory;
    private readonly IConfig config;

    public LogController() : base()
    {
        var container = UnityBootstrapper.Initialize();

        this.logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
        this.config = container.Resolve<IConfig>();
        this.contextFactory = container.Resolve<IContextFactory>();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Status")]
    public string Status()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Message")]
    public string Write([FromBody] LogMessage logMessage)
    {
        // Elided for ... reasons
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Performance")]
    public string Write([FromBody] PerformanceMessage performanceMessage)
    {
        // Elided for ... reasons
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Added WebApiService.Designer.cs, as the service shuts down when it returns from InitializeComponent.

**Edit 2**: I've traced it to `WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl)` in `WebApiService.cs`. A *TargetInvocationException* is thrown, with an *HttpListenerException* as the inner exception. The message on the HttpListenerException is "Access is denied."

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131604
  Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(IAppBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.StartServer(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(StartContext context)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.StartImplementation(IServiceProvider services, StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](StartOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[TStartup](String url)
   at Foo.Logging.WebApi.WebApiService.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\Dev\Foo\Foo.WebApi\WebApiService.cs:line 45

Inner Exception 1:
HttpListenerException: Access is denied
```

I've researched possible causes for this, and it could be the URL or an ACL. I changed the URL to `http://+:{this.config.WebApiHttpPort}`, to no avail. I then created an ACL as follows:

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:8089/ user=Everyone
```

The error still occurs.

Comment: What happens when you debug the service?

Comment: Since the service stops right away, I can't attach Visual Studio's debugger to it. I can run it as a console app, tho, and it works fine. Let me see what happens when I add Debugger.Launch() to the Main routine.

Comment: Nothing else in the windows application event log? What account is the service running under? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976425/running-self-hosted-owin-web-api-under-non-admin-account

Comment: @PeterBons It runs under a special service account reserved for applications. It has administrative privileges throughout the network.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I added a request for additional time (5 minutes worth!) to OnStart. That allowed me to attach a VS debugger to it. Oddly, it just stops running with no warning when InitializeComponent in WebApiService completes. It never gets to the call to initialize Unity. Puzzling.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've observed that, while I'm stepping through the code, no errors are occurring or being thrown, but the service just stops mid-execution. It's very strange.

Comment: @MikeHofer Could it be that there is some unhandled exception of those that cannot be handled?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I turned on all exceptions, and discovered that the problem appears to be the call to `WebApp.Start<Startup>(baseUrl)`. It throws a TargetInvocationException with an HttpListenerException as the inner exception. The message there is "Access is denied." I'm digging into that now.

Comment: Sounds like opening the port could be the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21634519/6320217

Comment: @DotNetDev The port is open on the server. You can hit it from any other server in the intranet, and browse the root of the virtual directory.