# Running self-hosted OWIN Web Site under non-admin account

Tags: c#, nunit, owin

I'm getting the error "system.net.httplistenerexception: access is denied" when running the following c# code on command line under Non-Admin account "Domain\test", but it works when running under admin elevated account "Domain\test"(e.g. Run as Administrator on Windows Command line):

WebApp.Start(new StartOptions("http:\localhost") { Port = 5000 });

I've been trying with different options as suggested at [Running self-hosted OWIN Web API under non-admin account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976425/running-self-hosted-owin-web-api-under-non-admin-account), but non of them works for me.

Can you please help?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019466/httplistener-access-denied) help?

Comment: Or, maybe, greater port number will help. `new StartOptions("http:\localhost") { Port = 54321 }` for example

Comment: Tried to greater port number 54321 as suggested, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Please see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

By default, non-admin accounts cannot create a URL reservation.  To allow a user to bind to a given URL, you'll need to [add the URL reservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/add-urlacl) on behalf of the non-administrative user.

For example, to allow `CORP\NonAdmin` to bind to any address on port 8080 (but only if it's followed by `/MyUri`), you could run the following in an elevated context:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/MyUri user=CORP\NonAdmin
```

If you wanted to see which reservations already exist, you could run the following:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

**Edit:**

I see that you're still have problems.  Please provide the output of the following command:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

The output should include an entry similar to the following:

```
Reserved URL            : http://+:5000/
    User: Domain\test
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-##-##########-#########-##########-#######)
```

**Edit:**

I see you've posted the output of the `netsh` command.

The SDDL for the first entry doesn't look right to me.  Also, because there are two overlapping URL Reservations with different SDDL values, Windows may be getting the two confused.

You may want to remove both URL Reservations and replace them with a single entry.  For example:

To remove the overlapping entries:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://+:5000/
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:5000/
```

Now add a single entry:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:5000/ user=Domain\test
```

Close all windows (maybe reboot) and try to run the console (self-hosted web) app again.

If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll try to help.

**Edit:**

The goal would be to create a single URL reservation that looks like this:

```
Reserved URL            : http://+:5000/
    User: Domain\test
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-839522115-1972579041-2146381891-8170)
```

Comment: I tried the following, but it still gets the sme error.

Comment: please provide the output of the following: `netsh http show`

Comment: I provided the output of this command: netsh http show,  as shown above, can you please help?