# Cannot use port in Asp.net after cheking the port by netstat

Tags: c#, port, netstat

I used `netstat -aon | findstr 28080` to check if the port is in use, and it returned nothing
[The command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZBn1.png)
 But when I want to use this port in Asp.net, the error shows like following,
[the error shown in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA9ub.png). Is there anyone encounter this before? I just want to know how can I grant my application access to this port.

I also tried 38080,48080,28081, none can work.

I am using the signalR to connect with the frontend, and the code where the exception occur is as following:

```
        string url = "HTTP://*:28080";
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))// Exception occurs here
        {
            Logger.Info($"SelfHosted Server running on {url}");
            Dosomething();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show some more code where the exception is thrown? And also, does it work by trying port 28081 for example?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976425/running-self-hosted-owin-web-api-under-non-admin-account, or start Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: Thank you! Running Visual Studio as Administrator solved this problem.